# When / how is the Room schema file being generated?

Tags: android, android-room

Which gradle task / Studio feature generates the Room schema file? Are there any circumstances in which the file generation is skipped?

Weeks ago I made changes which should have changed the schema file, but the file was not changed. Now I made a new change (deleted an entity, including the entity's reference in the Room database class) and now all the changes appeared in the schema file.

-> Why was the schema file generated now, but not in one of the many builds in the last days / weeks?

The schema seems to get generated more reliably when I delete it before building the project. But that obviously is not mandatory because it also worked when I deleted that entity today...

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780092/room-not-creating-json-schema-files-automatically) question, but I already have the following lines in my build.gradle:

```
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
```

```
    def room_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: Did you increase the database version number?

Comment: No, it is still at "1". The app was not released yet.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

Comment: It has worked before with version=1, so that can't be the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Room will generate a new schema JSON file if it 'sees' you changed something in your `@Entity` class that might lead to a new schema and/or if you change your something in your `@Database`, such as updating the version, adding or removing entities, etc.

For example, renaming a field in a `@Entity` annotated class should cause the file to be generated. Meanwhile adding a new field with `@Ignore` should not.

The Gradle task that actually generates the schema is `compileDebugJava` or `kaptDebugKotlin` if in Kotlin (both for the debug variant). Room is an annotation processor so it does its work during compilation, analyzing your code, generating new code and generating the schema JSON files.

Comment: I guess that "Make project" (the hammer icon) calls that gradle task, right?

Comment: Yes, "Make Project" should call that task, so should the "Run" button (green play icon).

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I made these changes weeks ago and the schema file generation did not trigger. I use "Make project" and "Run" multiple times a day...

Comment: There might be other variables at play, for example if your Room entities are in a separate module, Gradle might not run the compile task either due to cache or compile avoidance. Or maybe you just encountered an odd bug. But based on the Room source code (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room/compiler/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomProcessor.kt#155) the schema should be generated if the schemaLocation is given and the exportSchema property is true along with the schema having a change.

Comment: These other variables at play are what I'm interested in :)
The entities are in the same module and I encountered this issue several times.

Comment: any idea how to force generating schema for specific version of database?